# How to output comments in Descending order by date using wp_list_comments?

Tags: comments

I am using the following code to output comment html:

```
$args = array (
    'post_id' => 805,
    'status' => 'approve'
    ); 

    $comments = get_comments( $args );
    
    $comments_html =  wp_list_comments( array( 
        'page' => 2,
        'echo' => false,
        ), $comments);
```

I used `error_log` to output `$comments` and it seems to be in descending order, which is correct as the setting for comment display in `Settings > Discussions` is `"Comments should be displayed with the newer comments at the top of each page"`.

However, on running `wp_list_comments`, the order gets messed up.

I have set 30 comments to be displayed per page. For products with less than 30 comments, the sorting seems to be by date in descending order. However, for products with more than 30 comments (and with comment pagination), the sorting order is messed up.

How to make this work with `wp_list_comments` and comment pagination?

Comment: It is unknown what the callback function do. Please review the question and [edit it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/401818/edit) adding the missing code. Also, WooCommerce is off-topic here.

Comment: Hi, I tested the function after removing the `callback` and the issue persists if we have the `page` argument set. Without `page` argument, the comment order seems to be fine.

Comment: Does the problem persists when you add `&cpage=2` to the URL instead of passing `'page' => 2,` ?